# PHP OOP: Recasting parent object as child class

Tags: php, oop

Is there an easy way to recast a parent object as a child class, preferably by a method of the parent class.

For instance I may have a "Visitor" class and "Member" class which extends "Visitor". Upon success of the authentication method is it possible to recast the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a constructor in the `Visitor` class which would take another `Visitor` object and copy all the properties into the new object. Then this constructor will be inherited to the `Member` class and you will be able to create a `Member` object by copying an existing `Visitor` object.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I can think of is to initiate a new "Member" object, passing the old visitor object to the constructor. In the constructor you could pull out the relevant attributes and assign them to the new object.

Similar schemas could work just as well, but you won't be able to directly cast something as a class in php :[

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not! After the user is authenticated, the request ends so the Visitor object doesn't exist anymore. On hte next request, you'll load directly the Member object (I assume you have somekind of factory that knows to instantiate the relevant object for each user type)