# Instantiate object as parent or child class without knowing which until constructor (PHP)

Tags: php, oop, member, derived-class

What's the best way to instantiate an object as either an instance of a parent class or an instance of a derived class, if you don't know which one to instantiate it as until *after* you start the instantiation (e.g., because the instantiation depends on data pulled from a database, which is only done during the instantiation within the class constructor)?  Example:

```
class Thing { // parent class
  public $thing_type
  function __construct($thing_id) {
    /* database access code that sets $thing_type as either 'normal' or 'special' */
  }
  /* Accessor functions, etc. … */
}

class SpecialThing extends Thing { // child class
  function __construct($thing_id) {
    /* database access code that operates slightly differently that the parent constructor, */
    /* but which also sets $thing_type, presumably always as 'special'        */
  }
}
```

So I could do:

```
$thing = new Thing($thing_id);
if ($thing->thing_type == 'special') {
  unset($thing);
  $thing = new SpecialThing($thing_id);
}
```

but this seems wasteful because it involves running a whole constructor on an object that is promptly deleted, and involves two database calls instead of one.  I was thinking maybe it might be possible to call the child constructor from the parent class somehow, like this (but probably not exactly like this):

```
class Thing { // parent class
  public $thing_type
  function __construct($thing_id) {
    /* database access code that sets $thing_type */
    if ($this->thing_type == 'special') {
      $this = new SpecialThing($thing_id);
    }
  }
  /* Accessor functions, etc. … */
}
```

But that still involves two database calls, even if it would work (not sure, haven't tried it).

There must be a "right" way to do what I want to do--I just don't know what it is.

The closest other stackoverflow question I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132348/php-oop-recasting-parent-object-as-child-class), which suggests defining a constructor in the parent class that would take a parent object and copy all the properties into the new object. Then this constructor would be inherited to the child class, enabling creation of a child object by copying an existing parent object.  But I'm not sure what this means or how to implement it.

(Using PHP 8.1.5.)

Comment: There's not much you can do here if your objects pull more data in the constructor. What has already happened, and what do you already know, that lets you pass in an `id` in the first place?

Comment: It seems you've got the whole thing backwards and tied yourself in knots. Maybe you actually need a separate function which queries the database and then returns an object of the right type.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans The ID variable can be, for example, a sanitized integer GET variable input from a URL.

Comment: Let's say you've got four classes, `Banana`, `Car`, `Animal` and `Dog extends Animal`, and you are given `3` as the ID? How could anyone know which class to construct? As noted, you need a function/factory. You give it an ID, perform your custom logic which might include going to the database, and then return the object instance that you want? The object doesn't decide, your function external to the object decides.

Comment: First of all you should not include database code in your thing to load itself. If your data has to be loaded, do it before you instantiate your entity (use repository or service). Then it becomes trivial because you already have the data and can use simple if else. More complex solution would be to use something like a factory pattern.

Comment: In any solution you will end up needing to call another method to get an instance of the correct class back. To reduce the number of database calls, you can fetch the row first and use your logic on it while it's still in the array/stdClass form. Then add a method on your class that can initialise from an array/stdClass (array is generally simpler).